# Update content of a form wrt to previous entries

Tags: html

I'm trying to update the contents of a form elements dynamically with respect to the entries given to other form elements.

Here is what i've done till now-

```
<form action="invoice.php" method="get">
<input class="form-field" type="date" name="date" value=""      
placeholder="Date">
<input class="form-field" type="text" name="product_name" value=""  
placeholder="Product Name">
<input class="form-field" type="text" name="units" value=""   
placeholder="Product Unit">
<input class="form-field" type="text" name="wholesale_price" value="" 
placeholder="Whole Sale Price">
<input class="form-field" type="text" name="sell_price" value="" 
placeholder="Sell Price">
<input class="form-field" type="text" name="" value="" 
placeholder="Profit">
<button type="submit" class="form-btn" name="button">Add Product</button>
</form>
```

So when, I'll update the last 4 form elements, profit will be calculated & shown in respected field. However, I'm not able to do it, because I've no idea about it. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Get this input form js calcuate And put in input 
You can get by mane or use id to get And set data in input

Comment: so document.getElementById("profit")=((document.getElementById("units")*document.getElemenetById("sale_price"))-((document.getElementById("units")*document.getElemenetById("wholesale_price"));  ?

Comment: if all inputs are number then use parseInt or parseFloat to convert string to number, better if you use twice or more this same input then write to var like: var units = parseFloat(document.getElementById(‌​"units")), salePrice = parseFloat(document.ge‌​tElemenetById("sale_‌​price")), wholesalePrice = parseFloat(document.getElem‌​enetById("wholesale_‌​price")); check if all vars not NaN (converting error string to number) and if not then calcualte and write to input

Comment: How to write back? will it be like document.getElementById("profit").value=//calculations;

Comment: As you wrote earlier
<input class="form-field" type="text" name="" value="" 
placeholder="Profit" id="profil">

document.getElementById("profit")=calculatedValue;